# Change CSS with AngularJS depends on textbox value

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I have two textbox in where I entered numeric value.

```
<input type="text" id="perse1" ng-init="perse1=0" ng-model="perse1" />
<input type="text" id="perse2" ng-init="perse2=0" ng-model="perse2" />
```

I have a label where I calculate the sum

```
Total value is <label>{{(parse1*1) + (parse2*1)}}</label>
```

Now I want to apply different css on this label. When total value is equal to 100 then `.alert-success` other wise `.alert-warning`.

I have tried following code but nothing work.

```
<label ng-model="total" ng-class="'alert-success': total.text==100,'alert-warning': total.text!=100">{{(parse1*1) + (parse2*1)}}</label>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, **fix the typos** (`parse1` != `perse1`, etc.).

Then you can **repeat the calculation in ng-class** (to avoid introducing another model):

```
<label ng-class="{'alert-success': perse1 + perse2==100,'alert-warning': perse1 + perse2 !=100}">
    {{(perse1*1) + (perse2*1)}}
</label>
```

I didn't include multiplication by 1, but feel free to add it.

---

Here is a fully working example:

```css
.alert-success {
  color: green;
  }

.alert-warning {
  color: red;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app>
<input type="number" id="perse1" ng-init="perse1=0" ng-model="perse1" />
<input type="number" id="perse2" ng-init="perse2=0" ng-model="perse2" />

<label ng-class="{'alert-success': (perse1 + perse2==100),'alert-warning': (perse1 + perse2 !=100)}">
    {{perse1 + perse2}}
</label>
```